# configuring GMap.NET for .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmap.net

How can i configure GMap.NET for c# .NET 4.0 . I found this " If you target .NET4, use this configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><configuration><startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" ><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />   </startup ></configuration >
```

"
but i don't know where to put this code

Regards,
Alex Badescu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to find the **app.config** file in the project. That configuration should go there.

Comment: No problem. Although Jon was faster with his answer :).

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an [app.config file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx) to me (which will be renamed automatically by VS based on your assembly name).